# Ending a function in C++

Tags: c++, qt, function

I have a C++ function called `write()` that is supposed to write a large number of bytes on the users HDD. This woud normally take more than 30 seconds, so I want to give the user the ability to `Abort operation` from a GUI (created with Qt).

So I have the button `generate_button`. When this button is `clicked()`, I want to have something to end the function, wherever its progress is.

I thought about threads, but I am not sure. Can you advice me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a thread. It should be quite simple to check a variable to see if the operation has been canceled.

Use a mutex to lock access to your cancel variable. That will make sure it is read and written in a proper way for multiple threads. [Another option is if you are using C++11 use an atomic variable.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/)

Break your large write into blocks of smaller size. 8 to 64 kilobytes should work. After writing each block check your cancel variable and if set, exit the thread.

Comment: yes, I am using C++11. I am going to accept your answer, but can you write some code to demonstrate the atomic variable please?

Comment: @Victor: I stole the reference link to atomics from Zac and put it into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Place the code that actually does the writing in a worker thread.  Have a shared variable (one that is either atomic, or protected by a mutex).  Have the worker thread check its value each iteration.  If the user presses the "Abort" button, set the value for the variable.

You **should** use threads if this is a long running operation.

Since you are using C++11, [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/) would probably serve you well.

Comment: Well, in Windows it might be done without threads by using a loop with write and PeekMessage. Qt probably has something similar.

Comment: @ZanLynx Even if you were to use the OverlappedIO features, a thread is still created for you underneath.  The only way to really do it entirely without a separate thread is to do something in response to a specific message (e.g. WM_IDLE), which gets very messy.

Comment: @ZanLynx There are a lot of unnecessary hurdles to using a solution like that.  Especially with today's hardware (multi-core systems), creating a separate worker thread is the better solution all the way around.

Answer (score 1):

Threaded guarantees that you will have a responsive GUI.  But there is a learning curve to using a thread in this manner.

A threadless way to do this is to have in your routine that writes to the harddrive in the GUI thread, but gives time to the GUI thread to stay responsive.

```
QObject::connect(my_cancel_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), file_writer, SLOT(setCanceled()));

// open file for writing
QFile file("filename.txt");
file.open(//... );//

while(still_have_data_to_write && !canceled)
{
    write( <1 MB of data> ); // or some other denomination of data

    qApp->processEvents();// allows the gui to respond to events such as clicks on buttons

    // update a progress bar... using a counter as a ratio of the total file size
    emit updateProgressBar(count++);
}

if( canceled )
{
     file.close();
     // delete the partial file using QDir
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will try a method asap, but I think I will keep the answer that I've already accepted, because My library is intended to work in pure C++, without any other library (as you mentioned here about Qt)